# Chances of getting an US F1 visa after refusal under 212(a)(3)(a)i on re-application

Tags: usa, study, refusal

My US F1 visa application was refused under 212(A)(3)(a)i after administrative processing under 221(g). What are my chances of getting the visa on a fresh application? The USCIS have refused it again for the second time itself. The visa officer at the US Consulate handed me an administrative processing right after my visa interview. I submitted all such supporting docs as instructed by the official letter within two days of my interview. Any update on this particular issue would be thankfully acknowledged.

Comment: Questions about long-term visits (e.g., moving to another country to study or work) are off-topic, here, but can be asked at [expatriates.se]. However, people can only really guess about whether you'll get your visa or not. If you believe that you've solved the problems that caused your application to be rejected, then it's possible that you'll get the visa now; if you haven't solved those problems, you'll just be rejected again.

Comment: Um, I think that section is about espionage and sabotage. They think you'll be spying for your or another's government.

Comment: You say you've been refused twice already. That alone suggests that your chances are poor now. Further, you seem to have been refused on security grounds. Unless you can find a compelling argument against that your chances of getting a visa are effectively nil. If you really **must** go to the US, consult an immigration lawyer.

Comment: Technology transfer issues are likely to depend on both the subject and the OP's nationality.

Answer (score 6):

This kind of denial is related to specialized knowledge. [INA 212(A)(3)(a)(i)(II) says:](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182)

> to violate or evade any law prohibiting the export from the United States of goods, technology, or sensitive information,

While not certain, it is likely that the denial was triggered by the nature of your intended studies, for example, very advanced (PhD level) chemistry or physics.  NOAA website has [some basic information about export-controlled information](https://www.wrc.noaa.gov/wrso/security_guide/export.htm), while [UC Davis explains how this is applied to university studies](https://research.ucdavis.edu/wp-content/uploads/Export-Control-Overview-of-Regulations.pdf).

If you read the explanation from UC Davis, you will see that it matters a great deal exactly how your studies are planned and presented.  It's possible that this was not adequately considered and addressed in the materials you submitted previously.

Your citizenship may also play a role in the denial, particularly if you are a citizen of a country that might be a potential military adversary of the US.  I imagine the US government may scrutinize such citizens more carefully when evaluating export-controlled information issues.

Since you already received a denial, any new application will be subject to even more scrutiny.  The chance of success depends on whether the new application is better at addressing these issues.

Your US university should be concerned about your visa denial, since it affects their ability to conduct their academic program.  To get the best help available, you should discuss the situation with all relevant parties at your US university, which includes at least (a) your academic department, (b) the international office, and most importantly (c) the export control office.  If you can't find the export control office, this will be a problem that may require outside expertise, as it is crucial that you and your academic department get guidance from an expert in export control issues before you reapply.